# Recyclerview dost not match its parent. it has a small space at the bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This image will show you what I am facing. Those pics are contained by a "child" recyclerview ( this recyclerview is an item of "parent" recyclerview"). this is my code

```
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:minHeight="200dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/left_messages_background"
                    android:id="@+id/multiple_media_list"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>




            </FrameLayout>
```

and the item layout :

```
          <FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                  android:background="@color/black"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"
                  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:id="@+id/img_row_multiple_media"/>
         </FrameLayout>
```

this is the complete code, I wrap the recyclerview inside a framelayout . the framelayout is inside the cardview and relativelayout wrap the cardview :

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout_media">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/light_grey"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:minHeight="200dp"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"

                    android:id="@+id/multiple_media_list"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


            </FrameLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: sorry. I forgot that after add the picture :V

Comment: What is the parent of Frame Layout?

Comment: Relativelayout , sir

Answer (score 0):

add `android:clipToPadding="false"`  to your RecyclerView layout in .xml